# search one file's lines for a partial match in another file (Mac/Linux/Unix command line)

Tags: linux, email, unix, csv, grep

I have two text files. One is a CSV file with name, email address and other fields. The other contains only email addresses. Is there an easy way to search the CSV file and output only the lines that do not have a match in the "list of email addresses" file?

If someone can point me in the right direction, I'd be happy to figure it out and post the answer for others. My guess is that I need to do something with cat and grep, but my Google searches (and stack overflow searches) along with efforts on the command line have not been effective thus far.

While I could easily do the same thing in Excel or even SQL, this is going to be an ongoing need so a shell command would be much better in that there wouldn't be a need for steps of downloading CSV files, converting to Excel or importing into a database.

Thanks in advance for any guidance - 
Chris

Comment: fgrep -v -f filewithaddresslist filetosearch.csv

Comment: that could lead to incorrect results, since you are not matching email addresses against the email field in the CSV but against an entire CSV line

Comment: I might be doing something wrong but the resulting output of that command is an exact match for the original file.

@isedev - right, I need the list of items where the email isn't found in a subset of a given line. 

I have a simple fix for this today, but I would love to be able to script it for the future.

Comment: @ChrisLarkin: the solution I gave you doesn't work?

Comment: Hi - I just saw it! Thank you so much, I will test as soon as I can get back to that system and post a reply.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think that the other fields might also contain email addresses. @isedev is absolutely right. But I'm not sure why `fgrep` could find no matches at all in the csv file. You mentioned in a later comment that the email address file contains CRLFs. Are there actually CR's in that file? `grep`, `fgrep`, etc. on Unix consider CRs as normal characters and if they're in the pattern file, it will look for them in the target file. LF is what they use as the line delimiter.

Comment: They do have CRLFs because they were altered on Windows, this could very well be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `awk` as follows:

```
awk -F, 'NR == FNR {file1[$1]; next} !($2 in file1)' /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2
```

where `file1` contains is the file containing email addresses only and `file2` is the CSV file.

The `awk` program loads all the email addresses in an array and then checks the second field in `file2` has a match in the array (and if not, prints the entire corresponding line from `file2` - this part is implicit). The program assumes the field delimiter is really a comma; if not, set the actual delimiter using the `-F` option. The program also assumes email addresses are stored in the second field of the CSV file; if not, change `$2` to `$x` where `x` is the field number (starting with 1).

You may run into problems in the list of email addresses is very long as it is stored in memory.

Example:

```
file1:
email2
email3

file2:
name1,email1,other1,otherother1
name2,email2,other2,otherother2
name3,email3,other3,otherother3
name4,email4,other4,otherother4

output:
name1,email1,other1,otherother1
name4,email4,other4,otherother4
```

**UPDATE**: if the CSV can contain quoted email addresses, you should strip the quotes as follows:

```
awk -F, 'NR == FNR {file1[$1]; next} 
         { if($2~/^".*"$/) { email=substr($2,2,length($2)-2) } else { email=$2 } 
           if(!(email in file1)) {print $0} }' /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2
```

Comment: That command, while nearly instant vs over an hour for that fgrep line, had the same result. The output file contained every line. The email field is the first one, so I changed the $2 accordingly; however, there are some fields enclosed in quotes. Could that be the problem? 

I have a file called PreferredEmails.txt (containing one email address per line) and another called List.csv. 

This is the command: 
awk -F, 'NR == FNR {PreferredEmails[$0]; next} !($1 in PreferredEmails)' PreferredEmails.txt List.csv > NewList.csv

Comment: Sure, CSV file:

`"Email Address","First Name","Last Name",MAGE_CUSTOMER_GROUPS,EMAIL_TYPE,MEMBER_RATING,OPTIN_TIME,OPTIN_IP,CONFIRM_TIME,CONFIRM_IP,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,GMTOFF,DSTOFF,TIMEZONE,CC,REGION,LAST_CHANGED,LEID,EUID
boln@gmail.com,John,Boln,General,html,2,,,"2012-12-08 21:36:43",24.148.81.237,,,,,,,,"2012-12-08 21:36:43",57169513,015a8038d1
droobie@yahoo.com,Larry,Baxter,,html,2,,,"2012-12-12 03:14:15",69.160.44.110,44.8141000,-68.7786000,-5,-4,America/Montreal,US,ME,"2013-05-22 12:11:24",57169677,21e75a3a40`

Comment: email list:

`johnj234@chicago.com
boln@gmail.com
layers@yahoo.com`

FYI I'm new to posting here so I don't know why those all show on one line. In the file each email address ends with CRLF.

Comment: Thanks for your help @isedev - I reduced the size of the file (number of fields) and your example worked. For now we're going to handle this without automation since reducing the fields takes time and I've already spent quite a bit of time testing and that negates any benefits we'll have for this monthly task.